# Call Powershell function from within for loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have written 5 functions as:

```
Function Task_1 {
‪#‎todo‬ 
}

Function Task_2 {
#todo 
}
```

likewise.

Now I want to call those function one by one from within a for loop as:

```
for($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++){
Write-Host Executing Task $i;
Task_$i;
}
```

When I run this, I get output & error as:

> Executing Task 1
>
> The term 'Task_$i' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

What's going wrong? Solution please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task_$i isn't the name of a function, it's just a string.

You can try using an & first:

```
&Task_$i
```

Or to be more literal:

```
invoke-expression Task_$i
```